# Context managers to connect to postgre with psycopg2

Tags: python, psycopg2, contextmanager

It is useful to connect using a context manager statements like this:

```py
with psycopg2.connect(**dns) as conn:
    with conn.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.RealDictCursor) as curs:
...
```

How should I define a class to work with database using context managers?

```
class DBConn:
    def __init__(self, dns):
        self.conn = psycopg2.connect(**dns)
        self.curs = self.conn.cursor()

    def __enter__(self):
        pass

    def __exit__(self):
        pass
```

Answer (score 2):

got it...

```
class DBConn:
    def __init__(self, dns):
        self.connection = psycopg2.connect(**dns)

    def __enter__(self):
        return self.connection.cursor()

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        self.connection.commit()
        self.connection.close()
```

Comment: How do you import and use it? I am looking for a solution, where I can only import one file/method and then share `cursor` among several imported files, so I don't have to worry about having multiple connections and closing the connection at the end.